# how to get value JSON in google API

Tags: json, google-api

I have google API, it return a JSON file

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=10.75,106.667&sensor=false

I want to get  "long_name" : "Hồ Chí Minh", "long_name" : "Việt Nam" and "short_name" : "VN"

I don't know JSON, I do like this

```
var API = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=10.75,106.667&sensor=false';
var obj = eval("(" + API + ")");
var obj2 = eval("(" + obj + ")");
document.getElementById("City").innerHTML = obj.results[0].obj2.address_components[0].long_name;
```

But it not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read a little more about javascript. You must use a http get request to obtain the json, there is 2 ways to make this, using synchronous request or ajax request.
Try this :

```
//the json url
var API = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?atlng=10.75,106.667&sensor=false';
//this function add the long_name
function addLongName(data){
    var long_name = data.results[0].address_components[5].long_name;
    document.getElementById("City").appendChild(document.createTextNode(long_name));
}
```

Using synchronous request

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", API, false);
try {
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;
    var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
     addLongName(data);
} catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
}
```

Using ajax request

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : API,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success:  function(data) {
        addLongName(data);
    }
});
```